# Is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ archimedean?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to show that $K = \{(a,b)|a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b)*(c,d) = (ac+2bd,ad+bc)$ is Archimedean ordered. I'm pretty sure it is. I've tried using that $\mathbb{Q}$ is Archimedean ordered but eventually got stuck. Proving that the natural numbers are not bounded in $K$ (which is equivalent to the Archimedean property) also didn't work.

Any suggestions or hints for me? It seems quite easy but I can't get it written down!

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't enough that $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2] \subset \mathbb R$ and and $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ are both archemedian?  Actually you don't even need $\mathbb R$ do you?

Comment: So far, I haven't shown that $\mathbb{R}$ is Archimedean ordered, so I can't use that. I think the goal is to use the Definition of the Archimedean property and the "set of positive numbers" for this field, which implies the way that those numbers are ordered.

Comment: It seems to me you do need $\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$ and that is not archimedian.

Comment: Of course $1+\sqrt{2}$ is neither rational, nor $\sqrt{2}$ times a rational.

Comment: I have tried this: If $(a,b) \in P, (c,d) \in K$ then I can assume that $a,b,c \in P$ (where $P$ is the set of "positive numbers"), so $a,b,c>0$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is archimedean which implies that there exists $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $an>c$ and $bm>d$. Further $(nm,0)*(a,b)-(c,d)=(nma-c,nmb-d)>(mc-c,nd-d) ... ?? ... >0$ which is where I am stuck.

Comment: I think showing that $\mathbb{N}$ isn't bounded is the simplest way. Pick $(a,b) \in K$ and find an $n$ such that $n > 2(\lvert a\rvert + \lvert b\rvert) > \lvert a\rvert + \lvert  b\rvert \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So: Let $(a,b)\in K$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is archimedean, there is $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $n>2(|a|+|b|)$. Now: show that $(2(|a|+|b|),0) > (|a|,|b|)$, or (in other words) $(2(|a|+|b|),0) - (|a|,|b|) = (|a|+2|b|,-|b|)\in P$ , where $P$ is the set of positive numbers.

Case 1: $b=0$, then $(|a|+2|b|,-|b|) \in \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2|x>0,y=0\}$, which is a subset of $P$.

Case 2: $b\neq0$: then $-|b|<0$ and $|a|+2|b|>0$. Since $(|a|+2|b|)^2=a^2+4|ab|+4b^2>2(-|b|)^2=2b^2,$ it follows that $(|a|+2|b|,-|b|) \in  \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2|x>0,y<0,x^2>2y^2\}$, which is (again) a subset of $P$.

Comment: Edit: Show that $(|a|+2|b|,-|b|)\in P$ or $(|a|+2|b|,-|b|)=0$. ... Case1: $b=0$ and $a\neq0$. - the rest of Case 1 is correct then ... Case 3: $b=0$ and $a=0$. Then $(0,0)=0$.